# Is it possible to use the double-tap on power button inside my app

Tags: ios, xcode

In the iphone X and on the App Store, user have to double-tap on the power button to validate an app purchase. Is it possible to implement somethong similar? Usually the phone will be directly locked after the first click.

**Edit:** I just noticed that the phone will not be locked if I double click the button. Can I detect this double click within my app?

Comment: nope. the power button is off-limit.